# how to use new image folder in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have created a folder in `app/webroot/`. for image placing. eralier by default img folder cantain image. which I have used some thing like this:

```
<?php 
   echo $html->image('foldopen.png',array('width'=>14,'height'=>'10','alt'=>'open'));
?>
```

now I have created new image folder insted of img folder. how to use this?

Answer (score 9):

use a slash at the beginning of the path. For example

```
echo $html->image('/images/foldopen.png');
```

Using the slash at the start is relative to the app/webroot directory

Answer (score 4):

Just create your folder in webroot folder (test) and use like this:

```
echo $this->Html->image('/test/image.jpg');
```

Answer (score 2):

I created one images folder in webroot dir. I used

```
$this->Html->image('../images/profile_image.jpg');
```

in my cakephp2.1 application. this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

or you can just change the `App.imageBaseUrl` in `app/Config/core.php`

Comment: I think this is the best answer, changing this config, help when you use CDN for images and keep your images outside /webroot/img folder

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your $html->image() statements short and modify the default image route you could always override the default behavior of image() by altering the config/tags.php file.

[more info on changing the tag output](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1449/Changing-the-tags-output-by-HtmlHelper)